# Virtuemart AJAX Cart pop up error over https

Tags: joomla-3.x, virtuemart, https

I'm working on an extremely outdated shop template, trying to keep everything else up to date for a client.

The client has set up cloudflare to be used as SSL which is pretty much all sorted, however when trying to add a product to the cart in VM3.2.0 the Ajax popup does not appear.

In the console the following error is logged

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.website.com/shop/outerwear/pretty-tomboy-athletics-hoodie' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://www.website.com/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&nosef=1&view=cart&task=addJS&format=json&lang=en'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

An example of this can be seen on this (link removed)

Can anyone advise how I can resolve this issue? If I turn off the AJAX cart pop up, I get a blank page - so there is a PHP error. I'm looking at this also.

Regards
D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, since you are now serving through https, you should also set the site as https in global configuration, so Joomla knows and works this way and have all its internal calls and assets from https.

Also, tweak the settings in CloudFlare for the propper connection of https between CloudFlare and your site wherever needed.

If you have done already so, then search in your Joomla modules/templates etc for any absolute hard-coded calls to using the http protocol, as those will not turn automatically to https despite your changes.